# how to display tables in html using dropdown list selcection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display the data based on selection in drop-down list.
for example if i select empty then it display all table data.
if i select 'a' then it will display data in rows 'a'..
please suggest how to achieve this requirement.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>details</title>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 0.5px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<div>

  <body>
    <h1>details</h1> 
    <select>
      <option id=""></option>
      <option id="a">a</option>
      <option id="b">b</option>
      <option id="c">c</option>
      <option id="d">d</option>
    </select>


    <table>
      <tr bgcolor="#C2D0C7">
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>URL</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">a</td>
        <td>site URL</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>site1 url</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">b</td>
        <td>site URL</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>site1 url</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">c</td>
        <td>site URL</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>site1 url</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


        
        <td rowspan="2">d</td>
        <td>site URL</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>site1 url</td>
        <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @vinay have you tried something ?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>details</title>
<style>
table,th,td {
border: 0.5px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<div>
<body>
<h1>details</h1>
<select>
<option id=""></option>
<option id="a">a</option>
<option id="b">b</option>
<option id="c">c</option>
<option id="d">d</option>
</select>

Comment: <table>
<tr bgcolor="#C2D0C7">
<th>name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>URL</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">a</td>
<td>site URL</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>site1 url</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>

Comment: <tr>
<td rowspan="2">b</td>
<td>site URL</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>site1 url</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">c</td>
<td>site URL</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>site1 url</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>

Comment: <td rowspan="2">d</td>
<td>site URL</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>site1 url</td>
<td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</div>
</html>

Comment: @MeerDeen please check the code and suggest the required changes please

Comment: @vinay update your code with in question not in a commend

Comment: @vinay let me check it ,i'll surely suggest you . And Also one thing you should Add these whole code in the question for better readbility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cooTry this using with jquery script. Matching the [**contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) word's from selected input

**Updated answer for  single `HTML` page**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 0.5px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function change(that) { //in this get the value of changing input
      var a = $(that).val() //its the value of selected data
      if (a != "") { //it's check the not empty condition
        $('tr').not('tr[bgcolor="#C2D0C7"]').hide() //its prevent the heading row `not()`
        $('td[rowspan^="2"]:contains(' + a + ')').parent('tr').show() //match the seleted value to display 
        $('td[rowspan^="2"]:contains(' + a + ')').parent('tr').next().show()
          //it matches the next row of other two columns it is the same in the first column 
      } else {
        $('tr').show() //it selects empty data show all rows
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>details</h1> 
  <select onchange="change(this)">
    <option id=""></option>
    <option id="a">a</option>
    <option id="b">b</option>
    <option id="c">c</option>
    <option id="d">d</option>
  </select>


  <table>
    <tr bgcolor="#C2D0C7">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">a</td>
      <td>site URL</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>site1 url</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">b</td>
      <td>site URL</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>site1 url</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">c</td>
      <td>site URL</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>site1 url</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">d</td>
      <td>site URL</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>site1 url</td>
      <td><a href=xyz.com target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think what actually he need is there in your post

Comment: @MeerDeen ...Ya is there  Thnks:)

Comment: @prasad Thank you, this is very helpful to me and i have 2 confusions..
1. This is not working in my local system, i have copied entire code in one html file and place the function 'change' in tag <head>..</head> but not working.

2.In this all the options (a,b,c,d) having only two rows, suppose if i have different rows in each option, how to handle..please suggest.

Comment: @vinay 1.function not in head tag use with in <script></script> tag see my updated answer .copy paste your local machine and 2.use `nextUntil()` https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil

Comment: @prasad thank you very much 1st one is working fine and for 2nd i have changed the logic like below, but when i select any option it display only one record, could you please suggest...
$('tr').not('tr[bgcolor="#C2D0C7"]').hide() //its prevent the heading row `not()`
        $('td:contains(' + a + ')').parent('tr').show() //match the seleted value to display 
  $('td:contains(' + a + ')').parent('tr').nextuntil("td").show()

Answer (score 1):

i am not Giving you the Complete solution but it will help you more.

## HTML

```
<select id="drop">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
```

## JavaScript

```
$("#drop").change(function () {
    var selectedvalue= this.value;

    if(selectedvalue==0)
    {
    //clear the table
    //get all results and show in table
    }
    else
    {
       //Clear the table
       //get all records based on  selectedvalue and display as you wish
    }
});
```